# How do I fix my checkboxes from checking when I don't click on them?

Tags: html

I've recently started using freecodecodecamp to learn web dev. I made it to the first "Responsive Web Design "certification project(Survey Form). I run the test on my code and pass but there is a problem with my html code that is bugging me. When I click anywhere near any one of my checkboxes or corresponding names it checks the "Action" check box. How do I fix this issue?

I tried changing the name and value attributes didn't solve it. I did research on these attributes but the descriptions are very vague. I tried putting all the inputs outside of the label which fixed the issue, but I feel like they aren't associated with the label anymore when I did that, so I put the inputs back into the label.

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <fieldset>
    <label id="name-label">Name: <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." required></label>
    <label id="email-label">Email: <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required></label>
    <label id="number-label">Age: <input id="number" type="number" min="0.1" max="120" placeholder="Enter your age..." required></label>
    <label id="phone-label">Phone Number: <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
           pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"   placeholder="Enter your phone number..."  required></label>
    <label></label>
    <label for="dropdown">What is the best Anime?
              <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="">(select one)</option>
                <option value="1">Attack on Titan</option>
                <option value="2">Bleach</option>
                <option value="3">Code Geass</option>
                <option value="4">Cowboy Bebop</option>
                <option value="5">Death Note</option>
                <option value="6">Demon Slayer</option>
                <option value="7">Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood</option>
                <option value="8">Hunter x Hunter</option>
                <option value="9">Mob Psycho</option>
                <option value="10">Naruto </option>
                <option value="11">One Piece</option>
                <option value="12">One Punch Man</option>
                <option value="13">Oshi no Ko</option>
                <option value="14">Steins;Gate</option>
                <option value="15">Tokyo Ghoul</option>
                <option value="16">Vinland Saga</option>   
                <option value="17">Other(Options)</option>
                </select>
            </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Is the Anime family-friendly? 
             <input type="radio" name="family-friendly" value="yes">Yes
             <input type="radio" name="family-friendly" value="no">No
             </label>
    <label> What genre is this Anime? <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="action-genre">Action <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="adventure-genre">Adventure <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="comedy-genre">Comedy <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="drama-genre">Drama <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="fantasy-genre">Fantasy <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="horror-genre">Horror <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="magic-genre">Magic <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="mystery-genre">Mystery <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="psychological-genre">Psychological <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="romance-genre">Romance <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="sci-fi-genre">Sci-Fi <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="slice-of-;life-genre">Slice of Life <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="supernatural-genre">Supernatural</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="anime-description">Describe why this Anime is the best:
              <textarea id="anime-description" name="the-anime-description" rows="3" cols="30" placeholder="I love..."></textarea>
            </label>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] so we can see what is actually going on. Preferably as a "Stack Snippet" so that the running code can be investigated here on this page.

Comment: Your label element wraps all the checkbox inputs. Each label should wrap _one_ checkbox or a set of radio buttons.

Comment: A label is tied to an input, so clicking on the text of a label will automatically focus the first input on that label. That is why you click on any of the names on that label and it only selects the first checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I definitely wouldn't place all of the checkbox elements inside a label tag, as that's most likely your issue.

Not sure if you have invested much time into learning CSS, but I highly recommend it.

In this case, I'd put all of the elements inside a `<div>` tag and use `style="display: inline;"` with the inputs inside that.

An example...

```
<div style="display: inline;">
    <label for="input1">Input 1></label>
    <input id="input1">
    ...
</div>
```